# We have to find the acceleration of block of mass $m$ just after the system have been released from rest

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

I have already solved the question and my answer is coming out to be$ g(√2/3)$ but in the answer key it is only $g/3$ by not considering the horizontal motion of the block B but due to the motion of pulley shouldn't the block be moving in horizontal direction too

[image]

Comment: Voting to re-open. Clearly a conceptual question about the justification for disregarding the horizontal acceleration of block B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key phrase in the question is "just after the system has been released from rest". At this instant the rope attached to block B is hanging vertically so there is no horizontal force acting on block B to give it a horizontal acceleration. Therefore in the first instant after being released, we can assume that the acceleration of block B is entirely vertical.

Of course, this only applies in that very first instant - as block A starts to move to the right, the rope is no longer vertical and can then exert a horizontal force on block B.